# Minimum sum such that one of every three consecutive elements is taken

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given an array of n non-negative integers (arr[]), we have to find the minimum sum of elements so that at least one element out of every 3 consecutive elements is picked.

```
Input : arr[] = {1, 2, 3}
Output : 1

Input : arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1}
Output : 4
We pick 3 and 1  (3 + 1 = 4)
Note that there are following subarrays
of three consecutive elements
{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 6}, {3, 6, 7} and {6, 7, 1}
We have picked one element from every subarray.

Input : arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 8, 6, 2,
                 7, 7, 1}
Output : 7
The result is obtained as sum of 3 + 1 + 2 + 1
```

The recursive equation for this is given as:

```
sum[i]= arr[i] + min(sum[i-1],sum[i-2],sum[i-3])
where the base condition is: 
if i==3, then sum(3)= arr[3] + min(sum(0),sum(1),sum(2)) where 
    sum(0)=arr[0]
    sum(1)=arr[1]
    sum(2)=arr[2]
result=min(sum(n-1), sum(n-2), sum(n-3))
```

Kindly explain the intuition behind the recursive equation formed. Why is it true that addition of the current i<sup>th</sup>  array element and the min of the results from the last three recursion calls gives us the correct answer for the array of size i?

Comment: The rescursive equation is clearly wrong, since for an input of { 2, 1, 1, 2 } it gives an answer of 3 instead of the correct answer of 1.  It does happen to give the correct answer for your two examples, but that is more by accident than design,

Comment: The construction of `sum` seems alright to me.

But isn't the true solution then `min(sum[n-1], sum[n-2], sum[n-3])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursive formula is indeed correct, but only if it is extended with the following:

```
output = min(sum(n-1), sum(n-2), sum(n-3))
```

... where *n* is the size of `arr`. In case `n < 3`, then the output is the minimum of all `arr` values of course.

The recursive formula fulfils the requirement *"at least one element out of every 3 consecutive elements is picked"*, which is the same as saying that the *index distance* between two neighboring picks (or the end of the array) is at the most 3:

- For *i* >= 3, `sum(i)` will include the value at *i*, and at least one of the values at *i-1*, *i-2* or *i-3*, because the `sum` definition for each of those includes the value at that index also. Obviously the index difference will be at most `i - (i-3)`, i.e. 3.
- For *i* < 3, it is true since there are fewer than 3 values preceding them.

The recursive formula (including the necessary formula for the final output), also fulfils the requirement that *"the minimum sum of elements"* should be output. This is because the optimal solution *must* include the value at index *n-1*, *n-2* or *n-3*, otherwise the other condition is not met.

- As `sum(i)` minimises the sum when *i* must be included, the minimum among `sum(n-1), sum(n-2), sum(n-3)` will thus find the optimal solution.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @trincot This sentence is troubling me "For i >= 3, sum(i) will include the value at i, and at least one of the values at i-1, i-2 or i-3, " wouldn't there be cases where `i` don't have to be included if sum(i-1) is included? for example is array is `{4,2,1,8}` then the optimal solution would be 1 right? but the current solution will give 9 because we automatically include the value at `i`.

Comment: That is where the `output = ` equation plays a role. You'll have this: `sum() = [4, 2, 1, 9]`, but then `output = min(2, 1, 9)`, and so 9 is discarded ;-)

Comment: That kind of make sense. But I am still confused on a few things. is there a different between `result=min(sum(n-1), sum(n-2), sum(n-3))` in the question and  `output = min(sum(n-1), sum(n-2), sum(n-3))`? and why do we have `sum[i]` and `sum(i)` ? Are we building a array also call `sum ` to store the result? Can you post the full snippet of your code?

Comment: There is no difference between `result` and `output`. I wrote `output` because at that time you had not yet added that `result` definition to your question. The `[` or `(` is just a notation detail -- it's the same thing. I have no code. Your question seemed to be about an algorithm, without any specification of a target programming language.

Comment: @trincot I see. but still, thank you for the explanation. it gave it a place to start. I recognize you from your answer of other question about the minimum number of steps to reduce a number to 1. You are great at explaining. I will come back to post an answer (code in the case for those who looks for it)  later when I figure out the algorithm and I will refer to your answer as part of my explanation. UPVOTE for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

base on my conversation with @trincot above. I was a bit confused about why there is a function `sum()` and list `sum[]`. I did a little search and I think it is because the solution involves using Dynamic Programming to generate a list `sum` and use it to store the answer as `sum[i]` if we are using the first i item of the input array.

If you read trincot's answer and got confused and wonder how the code looks like it looks like below (in Java):

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MinSumThreeConsec{

    public static int minSumThreeConsec(int[] arr){
        int n = arr.length;

        if(n == 0){
            return 0;
        }

        //if the length of the array lenght is 3 or less
        if(n <= 3){ 
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            return arr[0];  
        }

        //if array size is larger than 3 than we need to use DP to pupulate the list sum
        int[] sum = new int[n];

        //fill out the base cases
        sum[0] = arr[0];
        sum[1] = arr[1];
        sum[2] = arr[2];


        for(int i = 3; i<n; i++){
            sum[i] =  arr[i] + min(sum[i-1], sum[i-2], sum[i-3]); //include value at index i in arr. and the mimum value from sum[i-1], sum[i-2], sum[i-3]
        }


        return min(sum[n-1], sum[n-2], sum[n-3]); //refer to trincot's answer above
    }

    public static int min(final int a, final int b, final int c){
        return Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] arr = {};
        System.out.print(minSumThreeConsec(arr)); //empty case print 0

        int[] arr1 = {3,2,1};
        System.out.print(minSumThreeConsec(arr1)); //print 1

        int[] arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1};
        System.out.print(minSumThreeConsec(arr2)); //print 4

        int[] arr3 = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 8, 6, 2, 7, 7, 1}; //print 7
        System.out.print(minSumThreeConsec(arr3));

        int[] arr4 = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, -8, 6, 2, 7, 7, 1}; //print -1
        System.out.print(minSumThreeConsec(arr4));
    }

}
```

I think this even works with negative numbers in the list.